# Some objects return any while it has a type

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

I am trying to transfer my Javascript project to a Typescript project. I now have a problem that some Firebase objects returns any, causing I can not see autosuggestions in my compiler. I have this line of code for example:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore()
```

In my Javascript project when I type `db.`, I get a lot of helpful suggestions. In my Typescript project, I do not get suggestions, but only the usual Object suggestions. However, when I do use a function that isn't suggested at the autocomplete, it still runs. But it is really annoying I have to guess every method name. The problem occurs on WebStorm and Microsoft Visual Studio. Am I missing some imports?

The problem does not occur for classes I made myself, I get good suggestions from the compiler.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: What package are you using for `firebase`? What version?

Comment: Are you working with Cloud Functions?  Did you initialize your project with `firebase init` and choose TypeScript for language?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, I did all of that. I did firebase init, choose my project and than firebase init functions. There I choose Typescript

Comment: @charmeleon see my edit

Comment: That looks very old - the versions of firebase-admin and firebase-functions should be much newer.  Update your CLI and try creating a new project from scratch.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did it, my version of CLI is 3.16.0. Still the same problem when creating a new project

Comment: That's an old version of the cli.

Comment: @DougStevenson Autosuggestions work for me in my Typescript projects as long as the file extension is .js. Very strange :(

Comment: I understand that.  Code assist has always worked for me with TypeScript as well.  Have you tried my suggestions?  Update the CLI, then create a new project from scratch to see if it works.